# No xpath results in scrapy

Tags: python, html, xpath, scrapy

I'm using this code. The last two Values are there like that because I was testing to see if either one of them will work- they don't, though.

```python
def parse_again(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    meta = sel.xpath('//div[@class="LWimg"]')
    items = []
    for m in meta:
        item = PageItem()
        item['link'] = response.url
        item['Stake'] = m.select('//div[@class="stakedLW"]/h1/text()').extract()
        item['Value'] = m.select('//p[@class="value"]/text()').extract()
        item['Value'] = m.select('//div[@class="value"]/span/span/text()').extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

to retrieve data from this html source code

```html
   <div class="LWimg">               
            <div class="stakedLW">              
                <span class="title">Stake</span>
                <span class="value">5.00</span>
                <span class="currency">&#128;</span>
```

My `items.py` looks like this

```py
from scrapy.item import Item, Field

class Page(Item):
    Stake = Field()
    Value = Field()
```

The problem is that data is not retrieved, i.e. nothing is saved into a `.csv` in the end.

Any input is welcome.

Comment: you don't have `<p class="value">` or `<div class="value">` in html so you can't get `p[@class="value"]` or `div[@class="value"]`. Try `//span[@class="value"]/text()`

Comment: It's not working...I mean I'm not getting any results in  file.csv

Comment: Edit question and add URL.

Comment: @eLRuLL Why do you think that this is suitable for Code Review?  It isn't, because it is broken code.

Comment: Alright guys, well, my only problem is that data is not being saved to .csv file. Though, nobody here seems to be able to resolve that problem, so I'm forced to try other methods and different code until i find what's the issue. As far as learning python and scrapy, if i knew the language, I would not be asking anyone here for help. This being one of the reasons why i finally decided to register here and hopefully find help from someone who knows it , because I couldn't resolve it for days using google.  It's pretty clear that I'm new to it. If it wasn't, I hope it is now. @eLRuLL

Comment: program can not save data for many reasons - maybe page is generated by javascript and Scrapy can't get it - and why I asked for URL. Maybe there is other problem in different part of code. Maybe you should `yield` item one-by-one. Sometimes nobody can help seeing only part of the code.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/s3Qe7JZa Here is the url and the code. I've been trying all kinds of code, but no success. @furas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are populating the `Value` field twice, so just the last one will work, and I think the correct way should be:

```
item['Value'] = response.xpath('//div[@class="stakedLW"]//span[@class="value"]/text()').extract_first()
```

The other fields are not necessary, just the `link` one.

Comment: eLRuLL is the man for python and scrapy ! Thank you again for all the help, and thanks to other people from this community. I'm glad i registered here.